# How VSCode choose the font from the given font list in editor.fontfamily?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts

When I open the VSCode editor.fontfamily setting, I found there is a list of font family in the input field. So I want to know that how VSCode choose the font from the given font list in editor.fontfamily?

Does it choose font following descended priority, and what is the stategy? Or the font in different locations have different effects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "list" is more of a set of fonts, where the first one is the preferred font, the next one being a fallback, and so on.  It's not an actual *list* as far as a JSON object goes, it's just a string that's comma delimited.

```json
{
   "editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
   //                    first      second        third
}
```

You can test this out by simply switching around the fonts and saving the file to see how Visual Studio Code reacts.  If you put in a bogus font name as the first item in the set, when Visual Studio Code can't find the font, it will fallback to the next one. On Windows, if you supply nothing but invalid fonts, it looks like the ultimate fallback is Times New Roman (or an extremely similar looking font):

[image: bad fonts]

Comment: So that's it. Thanks a lot.